# Why does preg_match_all return int(376) instead of list of phone numbers?

Tags: php, regex

I use regex to get the phone number, but end up getting int(376) when I var_dump instead of list of phone numbers. Any help or reply would be appreciated. Thank you

```
<?php

$html=file_get_contents("http://www.senaraiscammer.com/");

$match='/\b\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}\b/';

$formatted=preg_match_all($match,$html);

//print_r($formatted);  // output is => 376 

var_dump($formatted);  // output is =>  int(376)
?>
```

Comment: By the way, the pattern is wrong. It can not capture telephone numbers like: `+60178882915, +6011-39983139, +60113988313`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the match count instead of the actual match results.

The correct syntax would be:

```
preg_match_all($match, $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regexdoc.com/foo.php)

Comment: Ya thank you, I just realise that, no wonder I keep on getting those number only. Thanks alot to you.

Answer (score 2):

[RTM](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred.

Correct usage would be:

```
preg_match_all($match,$html,$phones);  // This third parameter contains matches
print_r($phones);
```

Comment: Omg, thanks alot, I print the wrong variable..Thank you thank you, really appreaciate that.